# Hidding/Deleting Table View Sections

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, row

I'm developing an app similar to that of the contacts app. It has a list of items and each item has a detail view. The detail view is a table view and displays values such as name, place, value, etc. However, if place does not have a value I don't want it's section to appear so that there is not a blank cell in the detail view. I have 6 sections. Section 2 should always display even if was not assigned a value and section 5 have two rows. All other section have 1 row.
I've looked at other questions; however, I have not had much success. My current code looks like this:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return sectionTitles;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 1) {
        if ([[[detailGift givingTo] name] length] == 0) {
            return nil;
        }
        else {
            return @"";
        }
    }
    else if (section == 2) {
        return @"";
    }
    else if (section == 3) {
        if ([[[detailGift reasonFor] name] length] == 0) {
            return nil;
        }
        else {
            return @"";
        }
    }
    else if (section == 4) {
        if ([[[detailGift boughtFrom] name] length] == 0) {
            return nil;
        }
        else {
            return @"";
        }
    }
    else if (section == 5) {
        if ([[formatter stringFromDate:[detailGift dateGiving]] length] == 0 && [[formatter stringFromDate:[detailGift datePurchased]] length] == 0) {
            return nil;
        }
        else {
            return @"";
        }
    }
    else {
        if ([[detailGift notes] length] == 0) {
            return nil;
        }
        else {
            return @"";
        }
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 1) {
        if ([[[detailGift givingTo] name] length] == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else if (section == 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (section == 3) {
        if ([[[detailGift reasonFor] name] length] == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else if (section == 4) {
        if ([[[detailGift boughtFrom] name] length] == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else if (section == 5) {
        if ([[formatter stringFromDate:[detailGift dateGiving]] length] == 0 && [[formatter stringFromDate:[detailGift datePurchased]] length] == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if ([[formatter stringFromDate:[detailGift dateGiving]] length] != 0 && [[formatter stringFromDate:[detailGift datePurchased]] length] == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if ([[formatter stringFromDate:[detailGift dateGiving]] length] == 0 && [[formatter stringFromDate:[detailGift datePurchased]] length] != 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
// Crashes after returning value of two
            return 2;
        }
    }
    else {
        if ([[detailGift notes] length] == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This seems very messy to me and also it causes the following exception:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

If anyone could give me some advice or put me on the right direction I would really appreciate it!
Thanks a lot!
Scott

Comment: Can you add a comment in your source listing to note the place where the error is thrown? I'm presuming that you've stepped through it with the debugger, but if not, that's the first thing I'd recommmend.

Comment: The error is clear enough, you are handling an empty array as if it's not empty. Just log every array to see if it's empty or not. By the way, sections start at 0 (in this case the 'else' is filling the first section)

Comment: @RickvanderLinde Ahh! I'm sure that was the issue. My tableview has a set amount of sections so perhaps I was trying to access a section that doesn't exist. Thank you!